# Получить первые ячейки таблицы

Tags: html, jquery

Всем привет. Как с помощью jQuery вытянуть **все первые ячейки** таблицы и определить ту из них которая содержит определенное значение? Нужно выбрать именно **первые**.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
jQuery("table tr").find("td:first").each(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).html() == "<b>первые</b>")
        console.log(this);
})
```

Есть и другие варианты решения )

[< выполнить >](http://jsfiddle.net/G4rKv/)